# Multiple devices cannot connect to a TP LINK wireless TD-W8968 router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I've got a TP LINK wireless router, model TD-W8968. When we have lots of devices in the house (10 - 15, made up of laptops, iPhones, iPads etc.) we find that some devices can't connect to the network.

Things work normally most of the time but when someone comes round with extra devices we start getting problems.

I've tried making extra wireless networks (a feature that TP LINK offers) but that still gives the same problems.

How do we go about narrowing this down or solving the problem?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to indicate the exact model router that you have. Also, please add any applicable error messages.

Comment: Probably you have hit the maximum number of connected devices, check on the router manual, it should be stated here

Comment: You appear to have two Super User accounts. You should merge them. Follow the instructions [here](http://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts).

Comment: This is usually due to having too few IP addresses in the DHCP reservation block.